# not able to display remote image in table view - appcelerator

Tags: android, iphone, appcelerator

I am creating a table row with image view and in that image view image will come from remote url.

```
var pic =  Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        image:photoUrl,
        width:32,
        height:32,
        left:4,
        top:2
    });
```

here photoUrl is something like "https://xxx.xx.x.com/profilephoto/72990000000D6Wd/T"
on android its not showing anything and on iphone its showing some default image. am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

image url "https://xxx.xx.x.com/profilephoto/72990000000D6Wd/T" was redirecting to the login screen. it was working fine on browser because I was already logged in but it was not working on the mobile app because session id was not there.

So I have modified url like https://xxx.xx.x.com/profilephoto/72990000000D6Wd/T?oauth_token=[token]

Now its working fine.